# Overhead of establishing connection to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am wondering about the performance of connecting to the database. Is it okey to close the database connection between each query, or should I try to leave it open until I am done? Is the speed penalty of opening/closing the connection high?

Comment: @thecoon, not really, here OP asks about performance not how to..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADO.NET will "pool" connections for you.  When you close a connection, it's not really closed, but placed in a pool. When a new connection is requested with the same connection string, the connection from the pool is reused. The pool is so fast that in practice, opening a connection is virtually free.

A best practice is to open a connection when you need it, and close it right after:

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    ... retrieve data ...
}
```

If you code like that, you don't have to worry about connection lifetime at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is overhead associated with creating, opening and closing connections (some of this even with connection pooling in use), you should ideally connect once, retrieve all your data, then close and dispose of the connection. You should be sure to use the `using` approach so that you don't inadvertently leave connections open longer than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, the opening and closing of connection is good for `low volume application` but with `high volume application`, the cost of opening and closing the connection becomes significant. So, it entirley relies upon the context.While working for large application, the [Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) come into trick.`ADO.NET` definitely handles connection pooling.